# Eloquent Models inheritance problem (Customers, Suppliers, Employees)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent-relationship

I have some problemns modeling in laravel my web app.
I have Customers, Suppliers, Employees model, and a model Person for the shared data.
In my datata base i have the next structure
Person (id, cif, name, email, identification_type)
Customers (id, person_id etc..)
Suppliers (id, person_id etc..) 
Employees (id, person_id etc..)

A Person, can be customers or supplier or employee or a mix (customer and supplier, supplier and employee customer supplier and employee etc.)

How can i manage it in laravel easily?

Thanks.